# Cannot authenticate in custom Laravel test environment (codeception)

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, codeception

I am running Vagrant (homestead), PHP 5.5.12, and Laravel 4.2. I'm trying to configure codeception to use a testing environment for acceptance tests (running on phantomJS). On the homestead box I have two environments: local and test. I was careful not to double up on the default 'testing' environment, which  is reserved for PHPUnit tests.

My issue is that while I can use Eloquent to instantiate a user (and retrieve it), I cannot authenticate with that user for any of my tests. This is preventing me from running my test suite, 90% of which requires user authentication.

I have two sites defined in /etc/nginx/sites-available: myapp.app and myapp.test. I define the fastcgi_param APP_ENV to be local and test (respectively). I have also specified APP_ENV in my ~/.bashrc, so echo $APP_ENV returns 'local'. I have created the corresponding config/test folder with database.php credentials that point to the test database. Below are the default codeception.yml settings, and those overridden by the acceptance.suite.yml settings (which is the suite I am specifically running).

I cannot authenticate in the test environment. All attempts to do so return false or null.

#### codeception.yml

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=myapp'
            user: 'myapp'
            password: 'myapp'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

#### acceptance.suite.yml

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel4
        - AcceptanceHelper
        - WebDriver
        - Db
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://myapp.test'
            browser: phantomjs
            window_size: 1024x768
        Db:
            dsn: 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=myapp_testing'
            user: 'myapp_testing'
            password: 'myapp_testing'
            dump: tests/_data/test-dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
```

This acceptance helper compiles into the AcceptanceTester class and is run in the before filter on all my Cests requiring authentication. I tested the output of the User::create method here and it does in fact create a user object that I can access from, for example, within the login method. It doesn't, however, appear in my database (viewed from Navicat). The database is currently populated from the test-dump.sql file, and contains only the schema without any data. I'm not sure why the Eloquent creation method doesn't write to the database, but my best guess is that the db is being rolled back after the test suite has run.

#### AcceptanceHelper.php

```
<?php namespace Codeception\Module;

// here you can define custom actions
// all public methods declared in helper class will be available in $I

use AcceptanceTester;
use Hash;
use LoginPage;
use User;

class AcceptanceHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    public function loginUser(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        User::create([
            'first_name' => 'test',
            'last_name' => 'test',
            'password' => Hash::make('1234'),
            'email' => 'test@test.com'
        ]);
        $this->login($I, 'test@test.com', '1234');
    }

    public function login(AcceptanceTester $I, $email, $password)
    {
        $I->amOnPage(LoginPage::$URL);
        $I->fillField('email', $email);
        $I->fillField('password', $password);
        $I->click(LoginPage::$loginButton);
        $I->see('Welcome. Your email address is test@test.com');
    }

    public function logoutUser(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage('/logout');
        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/login');
        $I->see('You have been logged out');
    }
}
```

Below is the store action on the sessions controller which should authenticate users (and which works fine in the 'local' environment for myapp.app http requests). For login attempts on myapp.test, the Auth::attempt method returns false.

#### SessionsController.php

```
public function store()
{
    $this->loginForm->validate($input = Input::only('email', 'password'));

    if (Auth::attempt($input))
    {
        return Redirect::intended('profile')->with('flash_message', 'You have been logged in!');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->with('flash_message', 'Invalid credentials.')->withInput();
}
```

I dialled down right into the Auth::attempt method, which calls Auth/Guard->hasValidCredentials.

```
protected function hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials)
{
    return ! is_null($user) && $this->provider->validateCredentials($user, $credentials);
}
```

This returns null. To clarify, it even returns null IMMEDIATELY after a call to $user->first_name returns true, or User::all()->first()->first_name returns the correct first name. In other words, I can create and then retrieve a user using Eloquent, and then immediately afterwards test the Auth::attempt which ultimately calls hasValidCredentials, which calls Eloquent/Builder->where, looks up based on the email address of the login form, and returns null. Is it possible the user is stored in memory and not in the database?

I have manually created a user and tried authenticating manually, and the login form simply reloads. I have no such issues authenticating in the 'local' environment.

The below method is called during authentication, and returns a query object that contains a null result.

#### Eloquent/Builder.php line: 569

```
call_user_func_array(array($this->query, 'where'), func_get_args());
```

Below is my UserCest.php file. The BaseAcceptanceHelper merely calls the AcceptanceTester->login function to authenticate the default test user. This fails.

#### UserCest.php

```
use MyApp\Helpers\TestHelpers\BaseAcceptanceHelper;

class UserCest extends BaseAcceptanceHelper {

    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        parent::_before($I);
    }

    public function _after()
    {
    }

    public function view_profile(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantTo("view a user's profile");

        $I->amOnPage('users');

        NavBarComponent::goToMyProfile($I);

        $I->seeInCurrentUrl('profile');
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm completely at a loss as to why authentication is failing.

Comment: Try removing Laravel4 from the Acceptance suite. The Laravel4 module is only for Functional and Unit tests - not for acceptance tests.

Comment: I'm aware that the documentation states that, but I think it's a question of principle rather than function. Laravel4 just gives access to the Laravel application, which is essential if you need to resolve anything out of the IoC container for your tests, which I do. The problem was failing to tell the Laravel4 module which environment to use (see below).

Comment: You should not generally be resolving *anything* out of your IoC for your *acceptance* testing. Acceptance testing should be running as close to the real code as possible. Once you start doing things like resolving out of the IoC container, you are doing more of a functional test, than an acceptance test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to define the configuration settings for the Laravel4 module, in the acceptance.suite.yml:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - Laravel4
        - AcceptanceHelper
        - WebDriver
        - Db
    config:
        Laravel4:
            cleanup: false
            environment: test
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://myapp.test'
            browser: phantomjs
            window_size: 1024x768
        Db:
            dsn: 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=myapp_testing'
            user: 'myapp_testing'
            password: 'myapp_testing'
            dump: tests/_data/test-dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
```

`cleanup: true` prevents the rollback of the db environment between tests, and `environment: test` tells Laravel4 to use the correct database.

Another issue I ran into, which I didn't realize at the time of posting, was that my 'test' environment folder had duplicated the cache.php and session.php configuration files from the default Laravel 'testing' environment, which assigns both the cache and the session to an in-memory array. No session data was persisting between pages, thus making authentication impossible. I just deleted these two files from config/test, and I was good.